# Cannot drop index because unique constraint requires it (postgres)

Tags: postgresql

Running Postgres 9.6.

I'm trying to write database migration code to drop a redundant unique constraint and index. The problem is that in some installations these index and constraint exist, and in others they don't.

The recommended way to drop would be:

```
alter table <table_name> drop constraint <unique_name>
```

But that fails when the constraint does not exist, and there is no "if exists" clause for this. There is an "if exists" clause to the "drop index" command, but that initially fails as well:

```
db=> drop index if exists <unique_name>;
ERROR:  cannot drop index <unique_name> because constraint <unique_name> on table <table_name> requires it
```

But wait, "drop index" has a "cascade" option to remove dependent objects, so we can use that!

Well, no. I get the same response:

```
db=> drop index if exists <unique_name> cascade;
ERROR:  cannot drop index <unique_name> because constraint <unique_name> on table <table_name> requires it
```

Note: I've seen a lot of seemingly-related answers where "cascade" solved the problem for people, but these all mention foreign-key constraints, not unique constraints.

Note: This does not relate to the fact that cascade is not supported when trying to remove the index concurrently; when you add the "concurrently" keyword, you get a very explicit

```
ERROR:  DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY does not support CASCADE
```

Is this a known bug? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a `DO` statement and trap the error:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE <table_name> DROP CONSTRAINT <unique_name>;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN undefined_object
      THEN NULL;  -- ignore the error
END$$;
```

Comment: absolute life saver